# Administrator rights for Windows application

Tags: c++, windows, api, admin, rights

I need to create and write to a file under C:\ on Windows.
This obviusly require Administrator right.

My application consist on:

- the CORE (.exe)
- two .dll

Now, I saw a lot of time software (like games) that require Admin right during installation and after they can do whatever they want; how is this possible?

How could I do that via C++ ?

Comment: Just intersting: "[..] require Admin right during installation and after they can do whatever they want[...]?" Which for example?

Comment: I think for example FIFA or F1 2012, they manage their setting under C:\Programs ...

Comment: Some games just modify the access rights on their folder under `C:\Program Files`.  Microsoft do not recommend doing this (although there was a time when they did), instead modifiable data files should be installed to `C:\ProgramData\<company>\<app>\...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your application to always run as administrator, you can specify this in your application's manifest file.

Specifically, you will need to add something like this:

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

More on [application manifest files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be found in MSDN.